# Passing props along from styled component using Emotion.sh

Tags: javascript, styled-components, emotion

I have the following styled button declared using `@emotion\styled`:

```js
const Button = styled.button`
 background: blue;
 ${size({
  width: props => props.width
 )}
`
```

In my code, `size` is a function that returns size css serialized style based on the prop that is passed:

```js
const size = ({ width: "m"} = {}) => {
 switch(width) {
  case "s":
   return css`width: 100px`;
  break;
  case "m":
   return css`width: 150px`;
  break;
 }
}
```

```
<Button width="s">Some text</Button>
```

However, the `width` value that I receive in the `size` function is not the resolved value from the passed prop i.e. `s`, but rather it is a string `props => props.width`.

Is there any way to pass the props along into a function from a styled component similar to what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work since you're passing an anonymous function to `width`, in a place where you're not expecting a function.

I'm pretty sure this is what you're trying to do:

```
const Button = styled.button`
 background: blue;
 ${props => size({ width: props.width })}
`
```

This way, you're passing an anonymous function in the scope of the styled declaration, getting the props from Emotion and free to use it however you like.